# Can we imply $\exists x\phi(x)\rightarrow \exists x\psi(x)$ from $\exists x(\phi(x)→\psi(x))$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

let $\Sigma$  be a consistent set of formulas in first-order logic and implies $\exists x(\phi (x)→\psi(x))$. which one of these statements is logical implication from $\Sigma$?

> a) $\forall x\phi(x)→\forall y\psi(y) $
>
> b) $\exists x\phi(x)→\forall y\psi(y)$
>
> c) $\exists x\phi(x)→\exists x\psi(x) $
>
> d) $\forall x\phi (x)→\exists y\psi(y)$

I think This sentence implies $\exists x\phi(x)→\exists x\psi(x) $ but the answer is $\forall x\phi (x)→\exists y\psi(y)$ how we can imply that for all x exist a y which $y\psi(y)$ ?! I can't understand it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Which kinds of deduction systems, if any, have you been using -- tableaus aka truth trees, natural deduction, resolution, ..., or so far just informal argumentations about structures? This will help answerers know what kinds of explanations they can use.

Comment: I used Natural deduction @lemontree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a counter-example to (c), you just need a single $x$ for which $\phi(x)$ is false. Then for this $x$, we have $\phi(x)\to$ anything at all. So $\exists x(\phi(x)\to\psi(x))$ is true. But we have no reason to infer that $\exists x(\psi(x))$.

As for your final paragraph: it looks like you are interpreting
$$\forall x\phi (x)\to\exists y\psi(y)$$
as
$$\forall x(\phi (x)\to\exists y\psi(y))$$
whereas the correct interpretation is
$$(\forall x\phi (x))\to(\exists y\psi(y))$$

Comment: I agreed (∀())→(∃()) is true but how we can say ∃()→∃() is not true ? @TonyK

Answer (score 2):

The inference $\exists x (\phi(x) \to \psi(x)) \nvDash \exists x\phi(x) \to \exists x \psi(x)$ is invalid because there exists a counter model:
Let the domain be $\{a, b\}$ and $\phi$ true of $a$ but not of $b$, and $\psi$ true of none of the elements.
Then for $x \mapsto b$, $\phi(x)$ is false so $\phi(x) \to \psi(x)$ is true, so $\exists x (\phi(x) \to \psi(x))$ is true.
But $\exists x \phi(x)$ is true with $x \mapsto a$ whereas $\exists x \psi(x)$ is false since $\psi$ is true of neither $a$ nor $b$, so $\exists x \phi(x) \to \exists x \psi(x)$ is false.
Since in this structure the premise is true but the conclusion is false, the inference is invalid.

The inference $\exists x (\phi(x) \to \psi(x)) \vDash \forall x\phi(x) \to \exists x \psi(x)$ is valid by the following reasoning:

By assumption, $\phi(x) \to \psi(x)$ holds of some object; let it be $y$. Assume $\forall x \phi(x)$, then in particular $\phi$ holds of $y$. By modus ponens, $\psi$ must also be true of $y$. Hence there exists an object of which $\psi$ holds, so $\exists x \psi(x)$ is true. Thus $\forall x \phi(x) \to \exists x \psi(x)$. Since an object such as $y$ is assumed to exist, $\forall x \phi(x) \to \exists x \psi(x)$ holds regardless of which particular object $\phi(x) \to \psi(x)$ is true of.

As an exercise, you can now try to translate this informal proof into a natural deduction proof.